# Size and placement of subfigure of different original size

Tags: graphics, floats, subfloats, width

I have a figure which has three similar subfigures and one of a different size (showing the legend of the other three). I'm having problems making the size and placing in the document look good.

This is my current code:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,trim=3mm 4mm 50mm 2mm, clip=true]{./Data_Figures/Coeff_evolution_LS_os.pdf}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,trim=3mm 4mm 50mm 2mm, clip=true]{./Data_Figures/Coeff_evolution_IP_p.pdf}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}%
\\
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,trim=3mm 4mm 50mm 2mm, clip=true]{./Data_Figures/Coeff_evolution_LS_p.pdf}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,trim=5cm 1mm 5cm 5.2cm, clip=true]{./Data_Figures/Coeff_evo_legend.pdf}
\end{subfigure}%
\end{figure}
```

All the figures are cropped as much as I could. This gives the following result, where the legend is too big:

[image]

But then I try e.g. changing the last figure to

```
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth...]{...}
```

the spacing is off:

[image]

Nothing else I tried worked either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With use of `\sbox{...}` you can measures the size of left images and then accommodate your image with legend to its height:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth,trim=3mm 4mm 50mm 2mm, clip=true]{example-image-a}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth,trim=3mm 4mm 50mm 2mm, clip=true]{example-image-b}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth,trim=3mm 4mm 50mm 2mm, clip=true]{example-image-c}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\sbox0{\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth,trim=3mm 4mm 50mm 2mm, clip=true]{example-image-c}}%
\includegraphics[height=\ht0,keepaspectratio]{example-image}
\end{subfigure}%
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Which gives (with using `example-image` from `graphicx` package):

[image]

With your real images estimating from your picture in question, the width of picture with legend is narrowed than other picture, so consequently ti will not protrude outside of text width.

If the aspect ratio of image is not essential, you can limit its width to fraction of available width, for example:

```
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth, height=\ht0]{example-image}
```

In this case the picture becomes:

[image]

**Note:** for positioning of images in second row the placement parameter of `subfigure` is changed from `[b]` to `[t]`. This would be good to do also for sub figures in the first row of picture.

**Addendum:** Another possibility to fit image with legend is to use the following code for the last sub image:

```
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\sbox0{\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth,%
                        trim=3mm 4mm 55mm 2.5mm,clip]{./Data_Figures/Coeff_evolution_LS_p}}%
\centering
\framebox{\includegraphics[trim=52mm -3.5ex 52mm 53mm,clip,height=\ht0]{./Data_Figures/Coeff_evo_legend}}
\end{subfigure}%
```

Considering this part of code and after appropriate trimming of your original images, special one with containing legend, my MWE gives:

[image]

Frames around images are added that trimming of images is better to observe. Of course, in real use these frames had to be omitted.

Let be noted, that measurement of image heght consider whole image height (with white space around it). Consider this height the legend image become to tall, so to it is need to add a white space below it which simulate text below graph (tick labels, axis label) on the left image. I estimate, that equivalent heght is `3ex` which I add to trim values.

Complete code with frames around image is:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{calc}
    \usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\framebox{\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth,%
                           trim=3mm 4mm 55mm 2.5mm,clip]{./Data_Figures/Coeff_evolution_LS_os}}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\framebox{\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth,%
                           trim=3mm 4mm 55mm 2.5mm,clip]{./Data_Figures/Coeff_evolution_IP_p}}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}

\bigskip
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\framebox{\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth,%
                           trim=3mm 4mm 55mm 2.5mm,clip]{./Data_Figures/Coeff_evolution_LS_p}}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\sbox0{\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth,%
                        trim=3mm 4mm 55mm 2.5mm,clip]{./Data_Figures/Coeff_evolution_LS_p}}%
\centering
\includegraphics[trim=52mm -3.5ex 52mm 53mm,clip,height=\ht0]{./Data_Figures/Coeff_evo_legend}
\end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

From code you can observe, that main your problem was bad trimming of image with legend (you left and top white space in it).

Comment: I tried this; see updated question

Comment: Nevermind the previous comment (and update), I forgot to crop the last image. Your trick works but now the last figure is too big again, as in the first example in the OP.  Changing the height as in e.g. `height=0.6\ht0` gives me back the problem in the second example of the OP.

Comment: What you mind with "to big"?. From your images is difficult to estimate their natural width. Also is not clear, how can be seen whole "legend>" image, id it is trimmed for 50 mm from its right side. I can only guessing. Maybe will help this: instead `\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth, height=\ht0]{...}` try to use `\includegraphics[trim=3mm 4mm 50mm 2mm,clip,height=\ht0]{...}`.

Comment: For what I mean with "too big", see the first image in the OP. The last suggestion gives something similar to the second image in the OP.

Comment: I have filling, that we are not understand each other. See addendum to my answer.

Comment: The reason I'm trimming the images is that they have whitespace around. I tried playing with how much trimming to position the figures but that didn't work. I think I'll just leave it looking ugly.

Comment: Please, bi so kind and test my recent code with your real images and add result to your question or my answer (just edit it) that I can see, what is the remain problem. Or make your original image available somewhere that I can test my solution.

Comment: Sorry I tried your last suggestion but forgot to mention it. Here are the files: http://dropcanvas.com/0nn1o

Comment: @jorgen, si edit of my answer. I use your original images, change trimming values and get to my opinion desired or at least nice result.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the legend being offset like this is because the `[b]` option to the `subfigure` environment tells it to align the contents at the bottom; hence why the bottom of the legend is sitting at the same level as the bottom of the `(c)`.

If you want to align to each subfigures centres, use `[c]` and if you want to top of each subfigure to line up, use `[t]`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{1.png}
    \caption{Foo}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{2.png}
    \caption{Bar}
    \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: centre aligned]

Comment: That helped, but didn't quite fix it; the last figure is still lower than the others.. Here's a picture using `[t]` (the best result): http://tinypic.com/r/121wx0k/9

Comment: That would be because it is aligning the whole subfigure, including the caption.  Since the legend has no caption, it might look a little offset.  If you want to manually tweak this, instead of `\caption{}` you could have `\vphantom{Gg}` which will create a vertical space the same size as the letters `Gg`.  Alternatively, you could have even finer control with `\vspace{1em}`; though that isn't quite as elegant :/

Comment: Hm can't quite get it working; vspace (tried it before) and just the vphantom does nothing, while putting the vphantom inside a `\caption` gives a compilation error

Comment: Perhaps it is because the `\vpsace` is actually beside the picture instead of below it?  You could try `\newline \vspace{1em}`... but that's really not a nice solution.  I'm sure there's a better way to do this then.

Comment: That works now, however rather than changing the alignment of the last figure it creates whitespace between all the figures and the main figure caption.